# Does Python 3 str.join() guarantee order?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Does Python 3 (standard implementation) guarantee that the following code always produce the string `2, 3, 1`?

```
', '.join(['2', '3', '1'])
```

If yes, where does this feature (order-keeping) documented?

If no, what function can be used to get an order-keeping join?

Comment: Why *would it not*? Lists have a set order.

Comment: Yes, lists have order, but this has nothing to do with the implementation of `join()`, if the author of `join()` is crazy enough, he can implement `join()` as something like `for item in reverse(LIST): item = item + ', '; return item`

Comment: And not add that to the documentation? And what would the use of the `str.join()` function be if it violated expectations in that manner?

Comment: Just want to know for sure.

Comment: That would be outright lunacy, and flatly rejected. If core functionality did do something like this, it would be very clearly documented (`"""This could join items in any order. What were we thinking?! #LOL"""`). If you pass e.g. a `set` you might not get the order you expected, but the order of a sequence will certainly be respected.

Comment: If the iterable is a `set` - then the join is not "ordered", i.e. `set_1 == set_2` does not guarantee `'.'join(set_1) == '.'join(set_2)`

Answer (score 8):

`str.join()` joins strings in the order the sequence you passed in lists the strings.

Since you are passing in a list literal and lists have a fixed order, your sample will always produce the string output in the same order, yes.

Rule of thumb: if the order would be handled any differently, the [`str.join()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) would have mentioned this explicitly. Not concatenating strings in the order the iterable provides them would be... *very surprising*, not to mention not very useful.

Comment: Yes. for sure.  I tried str.join() with set() --> mess order;  with List() --> the same order.